# MOSFET circuit design

Tags: mosfet, cmos

Consider this organization of P-MOSFETS and N-MOSFETS. A CMOS cell has a complementary property which refers to the use of both n-type (N-MOSFET) and p-type (P-MOSFET) transistors within the same cell to achieve enhanced performance and power efficiency. The question is: How many inputs allow for this complementary property to hold? [image]

Please tell me if I am correct with my truth table, which shows that 2 combinations allow for the property to hold? The answer options were 0, 2, 4.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but I should note that "Z" is not correct (under standard usage) for the two middle input valuations you give. This is a contention situation (both the PUN and PDN are ON) and therefore "X" is generally used here. "Z" denotes a so-called high-impedance situation on the output node which you have denoted 'r'.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me about that. Now since those two inputs (i.e. when x is 0 and y is 1 and when x is 1 and y is 0) give us a contention situation, would it mean that only two inputs (i.e. both x and y are 0 and both x and y are 1) allow for the complementary property of PUN and PDN to be satisfied? The question was how many inputs allow for that property to hold.

Comment: I see, I now understand what you mean by "complementary property" in your OP. I won't give you the answer but it seems you're well on your way -- ask yourself under what input valuations do I get precisely one of the two of PUN and PDN as ON.

Comment: Ok 2 it is! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit is easier to understand drawn like this, which is identical in both function and connectivity:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVivNJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Both the blue-boxed sub-circuit and the one in the red box are identical, and both are vying for control of the potential of node OUT. if \$X \ne Y\$ then there is contention, one tries to raise OUT, the other tries to lower it, and the result is a very low resistance between \$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{SS}\$, and lots of current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxosBo.png)</sup>

Here I have two unequal inputs, and both Q2 and Q3 are simultaneously "on". This produces a low resistance path between \$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{SS}\$, a near "short-circuit" shown by the red arrows. Consequently some things are getting hot, and the output is not well defined.

The MOSFETs in each individual boxed area may be considered complementary, because they'll never be simultaneously "on", but when the outputs of several such complementary pairs are joined, the *only* condition under which you don't have output contention is when all inputs are equal. You can extend your circuit to have as many such complementary-pair modules as you like, and nothing really changes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgqAdb.png)</sup>

The only condition when there is no output contention is when:

$$ W = X = Y = Z $$

If any of those inputs differs from any other, you'll have a near short-circuit between \$V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{SS}\$, with correspondingly high currents through at least two MOSFETs, some of which may die. Output \$
V_{OUT}\$ will not be a clear high or low, it will be somewhere in between.